# Neron Severi group: two descriptions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, schemes, sheaf-cohomology

I have a question on a comment from Daniel Hyubrechts' Complex Geometry [Complex Geometry](https://www.math.uh.edu/~shanyuji/Complex/Complexgeometry.pdf) on pages 133/134.

Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold. Consider the exponential sequence on cohomology

$$ ... \to H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^*)=Pic(X) \to H^2(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(X, \mathcal{O}_X) \to ...$$

> *Remark 3.3.3* Often, the image of $Pic(X) \to H^2(X,\mathbb{R}) \subset H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ is called the *Neron-Severi group* $NS(X)$ of the manifold $X$. It spans a finite dimensional real vector space $NS(X)_{\mathbb{R}}= NS(X) \otimes \mathbb{R} \subset  H^2(X,\mathbb{R}) \cap H^{1,1}(X)$, where the inclusion is strict in general. The Lefschetz theorem above thus says that the
>   natural inclusion $NS(X) \subset H^{1,1}(X, \mathbb{Z})$ is an equality.
>
> If $X$ is projective, yet another description of the Neron-Severi group can be
>   given. Then, $NS(X)$ is the quotient of $Pic(X)$ by the subgroup of numerically
>   trivial line bundles. A line bundle $L$ is called numerically trivial if $L$ is of
>   degree zero on any curve $C \subset X$.

Q1: Why in case of $X$ projective i.e. closed subscheme of projective space, these two descriptions of *Neron-Severi group* coincide? Thus why the image of $Pic(X) \to H^2(X,\mathbb{R})\subset H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ coincides with quotient $Pic(X)/A$ with $A$ subgroup of numerically trivial line bundles?

Q2: Why $NS(X)_{\mathbb{R}} $ is contained in $  H^{1,1}(X)$. Recall, we have decomposition $H^2(X, \mathbb{C})=H^{2,0}(X) \oplus H^{1,1}(X) \oplus H^{0,2}(X)$.